# Latching comparator always starts at latching position

Tags: circuit-design, comparator, latching, over-current

I build a over-current protection circuit using a latching comparator, below circuit diagram is the simplified version (without the current limit circuitry):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkXJu4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The problem is; on power-ups the comparator is always latched (when there's no voltage drop over R1), until SW1 is pressed. after SW1 is pressed once it will start working as intended.

How can I optimize this circuit to not latch on power-up?

Comment: Consider adding a power on reset to force it to the correct mode on power up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was as simple as adding C1, Now on power-ups non-inverting input sees a higher voltage for a short moment and that prevents the comparator to go to latching state.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5i8FV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Two things can cause this:

1. Power-on surge. The load resistance is very low when cool but increases while heating up. Tungsen filament lamps or capacitance in parallel with the load are examples.  If this is the case then the circuit is doing its job. Setting the threshold reference to accomodate the surge, either permanently or temporarily, can solve the problem.
2. The comparator reference takes time to stabilize during the power-on transient. So any current through the sense resistor may be greater than the reference during the stabilization time. The load power-on must be delayed, or current sensing must be delayed until the reference is stabilized.

Answer (score 1):

1. You could label SW1 as "ON/RESET". This may be even desirable.
2. There may be a transient on the load - say capacitors charging up. In that case the latching is by design, even if undesirable.
3. It may just be how the power-on "trajectory" of this comparator-based circuit is.

By the way, the LM393 will run just fine from a single supply. It doesn't need the -12V in this application.

The circuit was somewhat hard to read as drawn, so I've redrawn it below. I've also added a power supply supervisor that will keep the output turned on through the start-up transient - whether on initial-power up or on a load restart.

For a single-supply design, the diode from the 0.5V reference to the open-collector output of the comparator should be a Schottky. A 1N4148 or similar junction diodes would work well with a -12V negative supply to the comparator, but that's otherwise unnecessary.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBAe9j.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Why TL7712? It's a design only a couple years younger than the LM393. At least they are in the same generation :)

There probably are many newer chips that would be a single-chip solution for this problem, but their availability may be somewhat iffy compared to LM393 and TL7712.

Comment: Thanks, Isn't there a simpler solution without using an IC?

Comment: There are simple solutions but they have corner cases. Eventually you'll be reimplementing most of what's in 7712, so at that point why not just use it. Since you're using a quad comparator, you could look at what's inside of 7712 and use two comparators to get something comparable. You'd need a voltage reference though. TL431 would be the go-to choice.